# iPad's status bar sometimes disappears, leaving a white space - but I never hide it!

Tags: c#, iphone, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I'm never hiding the status bar but sometimes it just disappears.
The pattern seems to be that it happens after some fullscreen transitions
* Horizontal flip from one view to another
* Use QLPreviewController and when it gets dismissed the status bar is gone.

However, I can not reproduce it. It just happens sometimes. Never on the Simulator but only on the device.
Rotating forth and back doesn't help either. If I leave my app, the status bar comes back in Springboard. Going back to my app, the status bar is still gone.

Has anybody else seen this effect in a project?

Comment: I've seen this happen but as you say its not 100% reproducable. The only time I've ever seen something similar is when rotating the device, the status bar will rotate (leaving a white gap) but nothing else will. I will let you know if I find out anymore about this!

Comment: I just keep on setting the status bar back visible whenever my view appears...works, but is a bit strange...

Comment: Make sure you've implemented ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation  in each of your controllers.  I've found that leaving one off randomly on a controller in the middle of your UI tree can cause crazy stuff like this.

Comment: I do have that. Well, I just set it back visible :-)

Comment: I am having this same problem (not using C# though). This is how I reproduce:
- View something full screen using QLPreviewController
- Dismiss the preview controller
- Background the app
- Foreground the app
- The status bar disappears and the window's background color is visible

I cannot figure out why it is happening OR how to fix it. Where are you setting the status bar back to visible?

Comment: I'm making it visible again basically on every action the user performs on my navigation controller. But you might try setting it visible in willEnterForeground: (or whatever it is called) if your issues are coming from switching from back to foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Are you holding a reference to a `QLPreviewController` instance? I was able to solve this problem in my app by creating a new autoreleased `QLPreviewController` whenever I need to display a file modally, as opposed to reusing the same instance over and over again.

Comment: I have a static QLPreviewController which I dismiss. Next preview generates a new controller on the static.

Comment: Are you actually releasing the instance that you're storing in the static variable after you dismiss it though? If not, I think this may be your problem. If so, then why are you using a static variable?