# ipad and status bar problem

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uinavigationbar, statusbar

i have one ipad application in it .in my current view i gave navigation bar custom and view with custom image and one tableview with clear background color now when i navigate from my current view to previous view status bar area and navigation bar area become blank i have seen

[iPad's status bar sometimes disappears, leaving a white space - but I never hide it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084767/ipads-status-bar-sometimes-disappears-leaving-a-white-space-but-i-never-hide) which is same as mine question
but not saw  any answer

Comment: Realistically, you'd have to provide some code on how you are setting up all these UI elements so we can try to better understand the problem you are having.

Comment: actually i set image to the navigation bar and when i navigate to previous view because of in previous view i have set  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; there for navigation bar space become blank but if i comment this line [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; then it shows perfect but i don't need navigation bar on previous (first)view

Comment: In what part of both files are you showing and hiding the navigation bar?

Comment: actually in appdelegate in event applicationDidFinishLaunching i write code [window addSubview:[navigationController view]]; [window makeKeyAndVisible]; [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; for navigate to first view and in that (first)view and in viewwill appeear i have write [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; and  when i click on start button in that i set [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO]; for second view in which i have set title and button in navigation bar